# How to use paragraph in json?

Tags: json, getjson

I am new in android , I am having queries in json:-

How can I break the line in json if i having multiple lines?
 Like This:
{"contacts": 
[ 
{ "id": "c200",
 "name": "Ravi Tamada",
 "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country", 
"gender": "male", 
**"About": "Sentence1.Sentence2.Sentence3"**, 
"phone": { "mobile": "+91 0000000000", 
"home": "00 000000",
 "office": "00 000000" } 
}
 ]
 }

Comment: Can we see the json file you are working with?

Comment: { "id" : "7",
  "illustrationurl" : "../../Img/Illustrations/pursesnatcher25.jpg",
  "para1" : "sentence1.sentence2.sentence3.", 
  "title" : "“Purse Snatcher”"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just desire it to be a line break, use the code for the String you are using in the application. 
[Json are "data-only"](http://www.json.org/) for transfer, so they should not have any formatting.

IF the data is formatted, is directly as it should be used:

### Example:

```
{"MyVarName":"Sentence1\nSentence2\nSentence3"}
```

Then on lets say a javascript (using [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for simplicity)

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(output){
            alert(output["MyVarName"]);
        }
    });
```

#### Edit:

if you run the example, you will see the correct result.

The following will provide the correct results:
`"About": "Sentence1.\nSentence2.\nSentence3"`, if you are using another system, you need to writte the correct line break. meaning that in HTML the linebreak is `</br>`, in javascript it is `\n`u.s.f. check the line break needed then append in the position desired.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply but Sentence2 Sentence3 are not coming in next line.{"MyVarName":"Sentence1\nSentence2\nSentence3"}. my json format is {
  "contacts": [
    {
      "id": "c200",
      "name": "Ravi Tamada",
      "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
      "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
      "gender": "male",
      **"About": "Sentence1\nSentence2\nSentence3"**,
      "phone": {
        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
        "home": "00 000000",
        "office": "00 000000"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: You should really edit your example JSON payloads into your question ... it makes them much easier to read.

Comment: @AnshulKhare Check the edit. Also, on your STACKOVERFLOW questions add the ` char before and after your code, for better formatting